# is there a legit way to make a userlogin via API-Request on KeyCloak from the client-app?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, keycloak

We just had the idea to use KeyCloak for the user- and access-handling of our application, since we dont want to reinvent the wheel and have seen that keycloak is used pretty much. But we're not a big fan of a separate login page. We just want a small login-form on our landing page, which is beside the registration form conditionally rendered, depending on what the user wants to do.

So we want to call keycloak via request from the frontend to get the token in exchange for the credentials. And then for further requests our backend has to validate this token.

So i read about the OAuth 2.0 Password Grant and we managed to make with work witn keycloak, but its not recommended anymore. Since there is no intermediary step of getting an authorization code. Besides that there seems no wanted way to later change the password of the user via api, besides making use of admin rights.

Am I missing something? So there is no secure and common way to use KeyCloak via HTTP requests for user login and registration? If you use keycloak, then you have to use the login/registration forms provided by keycloak?

Comment: Keycloak has a rest API. You can login and receive a token via HTTP call. https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.1.1/rest-api/